# Sorting doesn't work in glossary when using custom command

Tags: glossaries, sorting

Writting my PhD, i wrote a command to set a glossary entry. This command set the sort as the label if not specified. But when printed, LaTeX doesn't sort them. Why does it works when using the native command \newglossaryentry and not when my custom \gle ?

The MWE is at the bottom

creates

[image: glossaries]

and the typeout call writes

```
## glossary: wrong, label: a, sort: a                                          
## glossary: wrong, label: b, sort: d                                          
## glossary: wrong, label: c, sort: c                                          
## glossary: wrong, label: d, sort: b
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[nomain]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][1]{% put glossaries on the same page
  \def\theglstoctitle{#2}%
  \par\noindent
  {\section*{\theglstoctitle}}
}

%set it with \gle{glossary}{shortlabel}[sort]{text}{description} % call it with \gls{glossary-shortlabel}
%FIXME sort wont work
\newcommand\gle[2]{\def\storeglo{#1}\def\storelab{#2}\glei} % glossaries and label are mandatory
\newcommand\glei[1][\storelab]{\def\storesort{#1}\gleii} %sort is optionnal, default is label
\newcommand\gleii[2]{\newglossaryentry{\storeglo-\storelab}{type={\storeglo}, name={\ensuremath{#1}}, sort={\storesort}, description={#2}}
\typeout{## glossary: \storeglo, label: \storelab, sort: \storesort} % expected output on terminal !
}

\newglossary{wrong}{wls}{wlo}{Wrongly sorted Glossary}
\newglossary{good}{gls}{glo}{Sorted Glossary}

\makeglossaries

%set it with \gle{glossary}{shortlabel}[sort]{text}{description} % call it with \gls{glossary-shortlabel}

\gle{wrong}{a}{A}{label A, sort A}
\gle{wrong}{b}[d]{B}{label B, sort D}
\gle{wrong}{c}{C}{label C, sort C}
\gle{wrong}{d}[b]{D}{label D, sort B}

\newglossaryentry{good-a}{type={good}, name={\ensuremath{A}}, sort={a}, description={label A, sort A}}
\newglossaryentry{good-b}{type={good}, name={\ensuremath{B}}, sort={d}, description={label B, sort D}}
\newglossaryentry{good-c}{type={good}, name={\ensuremath{C}}, sort={c}, description={label C, sort C}}
\newglossaryentry{good-d}{type={good}, name={\ensuremath{D}}, sort={b}, description={label D, sort B}}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sort` value is sanitized by default. If you check the `.wlo` file from your example, the sort value for each entry is the literal string `\storesort`:

```
\glossaryentry{\storesort ?\glossentry{wrong-a}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{\storesort ?\glossentry{wrong-b}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{\storesort ?\glossentry{wrong-c}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{\storesort ?\glossentry{wrong-d}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
```

So all entries have the same sort value.

You can switch off the automatic sanitization using `sanitizesort=false`:

```
\usepackage[nomain,sanitizesort=false]{glossaries}
```

The value will then be fully expanded when set.

Sanitization converts code into literal characters. For example, suppose I define `\teststring` like this:

```
\newcommand{\tmpA}{A} 
\newcommand{\teststring}{\tmpA}
```

Now `\teststring` is defined as the control sequence `\tmpA`, which will expand to `A`. If I then sanitize `\teststring`:

```
\@onelevel@sanitize\teststring
```

Now `\teststring` is defined as the sequence of characters `\` `t` `m` `p` `A` followed by a space character, so it will expand to the literal string `\tmpA`.

The reason `glossaries` automatically sanitizes the `sort` value is that more often than not the sort value shouldn't expand when written to the external file but should be treated as a literal string. The most common case is when using extended characters with `inputenc` and `xindy`. For example, if the sort value is `émigré` it needs to be written to the external file exactly as `émigré` and not expanded to `\IeC {\'e}migr\IeC {\'e}` which won't be sorted correctly.

When the `sort` value is set programatically, as in this question, expansion is needed so the sanitization must be switched off.

Comment: Did the job. Will read the doc to understand what sanitized means. Thank you !

Comment: @PTRK I've added a bit of information about sanitizing. Hope it helps.